# Store and prepare data in php with specific parameter request url

Tags: php, json, request

I have seen [here](https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=msft-c.json&callback=jQuery31101296552821441) this url json response data file from **Highstock**:

```
https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=msft-c.json
```

So the data (encoded in json format) taken via GET request changes every time that the `filename` parameter value is different, for example in our case we can call different data by using these other 2 parameters: `aapl-c.json` and `goog-c.json`.

How can be performed in php the same data preparation for store multiple data resources with different filenames values request? And can we call a specific portion of data by using different parameter values? Also a very simple explanation of the logic behind this process would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am skipping some verifications here, but the process is quite simple, this is a quite basic GET var analysis. When there is `?varname=value` at the end of th URL, PHP gets the variable in the $_GET array. However, it is quite unsafe to use it raw, you should filter it before.

Another advice here is not to try to load a file dynamically from this var value or these kind of things, for security reasons. It is better to only allow desired values (used a switch here that have a quite strange syntax, but if/else fit just the same).

Then with php, you have to create your document with a display, like `echo`. In this case, it is JSON, so you just have to output your JSON.

Would be something like:

```
<?php
//sanitize the value from $_GET array
$getVar = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'filename', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//do various things depending on value
switch($getVar){
    case 'aapl-c.json':
        $display = '{ "content": "i am JSON 1" }';
        break;
    case 'goog-c.json':
        $display = '{ "content": "i am JSON 2" }';
        break;
    default:
        $display = '';
}

//send the json data to the document
echo $display;

//terminate script for security
exit;
```

Comment: Thank you @Kaddath your example is perfect for my case!

Comment: you're welcome! you might want to check for the available filters though, this was a basic example and maybe another one fits better. Depending on the case, you might want to check the protocol too, or security tokens.. many things to say on the subject!

Comment: Can you update the answer with a couple of tricky example options for increase security in this case? Thanks in advice!

Comment: Sorry, but my day just got busy. What you have to consider is if your JSON resources will be public or not. If public, you don't really have any other specific concern that properly filtering your get var and not use its value on a loading path or such or eval. If private this is a really broad topic, i suggest searching in SO for access tokens, or session identification, things like this have many examples here